# Retrieve Magento store's base url in javascript

Tags: magento

What is the best way to determine a Magento store's base url from inside javascript?

I'm working on a reusable extension that needs to know the store's base url in javascript in order to do some Ajax calls. One would think a property like

```
Mage.baseUrl
```

would be available, but I can't find it.

An alternative would be to add the base url as a bit of inline javascript, but I can't find any information on how to add inline javascript programmatically (only external js files), without altering the template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default this information isn't (reliably, stably) exposed via Javascript.  You're going to need to expose it yourself via a custom block added to the layout.   The easiest way to do this will be

1. Adding the block via your theme's `local.xml` file
2. Adding a template to your theme for the above block

To add the block to the layout via your `local.xml` file, something like this should suffice

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block name="my_custom_js_block">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>my_custom_js_block/extra-js.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Then add the following folder and file to your theme

```
app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/my_custom_js_block/
app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/my_custom_js_block/extra-js.phtml
```

At this point you have a `phtml` template file that will be rendered on **every** page.  You can add whatever javascript variables you want.  I'm fond of a pattern something like

```
#File: app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/my_custom_js_block/extra-js.phtml
<?php
    $h = Mage::helper('core');
    $info = new stdClass();
    $info->base_dir = Mage::getBaseDir();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_custom_js_block_info = <?php echo $h->jsonEncode($info); ?>;
</script>
```

(untested, top-of-my-head code, but should work)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. How could I add this block from my module's config.xml file, rather than local.xml? I'm making a reusable module and can't rely on the user modifying local.xml.

Comment: Google around for adding a custom layout XML file in your module's config.xml.  Just like Mage_Catalog adds catalog.xml, you can have your module include a custom XML file.

Comment: After a few hours of searching and trying the _many_ contradicting and different methods to accomplish this, I have failed. Is there a way to know if my custom xml file is even being included at run time?

Comment: Make sure you're in developer mode and then introduce and error into the XML file.  If PHP chokes on including the file, you know it's being loaded.  See also: http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/16336482158/adding-additional-layout-xml-updates-via-modules

Comment: Alright got it finally. The key is that your custom layout file has to be under `/app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout`, NOT your module's `etc` directory. So I put mine at `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mymodule.xml` and got it working.